# MySQL Partition BY RANGE doesn't work with primary keys?

Tags: mysql

Is Partition BY RANGE can't be applied for the table which has auto incremented primary keys?
I'm asking it because saw some ([1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html),[2](http://vanilla47.com/MySQL%20Docs/mysql-partitioning-excerpt-5.6-en.html-chapter/partitioning-limitations.html)) examples of create table statement which doesn't have primary key definition. And also my create table statement gives me error:

> A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Here is my statement

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_point` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `cord_x` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `cord_y` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `angle` int DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (angle) (
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (91),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (181),
   PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (271),
   PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (361)
)
```

And one more question: could angle column be of double type? Because I've got this error when I set it as double:

> The PARTITION function returns the wrong type

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message is fairly explicit :

> A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

You must either partition by your primary key, or include `angle` in your primary key

I suppose you do not want the latter, so the former is the solution.

As for the second error:

> The PARTITION function returns the wrong type

Indeed, the partition function (here, "`angle`" is the so-called "function", think of it as the identity function) must return an integer, as stated [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations.html):

> A partitioning key must be either an integer column or an expression that resolves to an integer.

Comment: So it is not possible to have angle as double? Because cast() function doesn't provide double type

Comment: @Andriy Well, on the contrary, if you define `angle` as a `DOUBLE`, then you would need to cast it to an integer: `PARTITION BY RANGE ( CAST(angle AS SIGNED) )`. Still, this does not resolve the first problem, namely `angle` would need to be part of the primary key.

Comment: It's a part of primary key now. Thanks